# How do you add a color to this animated text in node editor v3.4.1

Tags: bezier-curves, text-object

[image]

Value > Value to String > String to Curves > Fill Curves > Transform > both Extrude Mesh and Flip Faces > Join Geometry > Group output
But where do I add a color to this text?

Comment: just use as last node before the output node a "set material" node - and please, next time you are posting something, make sure we can at least read your node tree. thx